# Constraints doesn't work properly for NSScrollViews documentView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

The content of my scrollView always start at the bottom left like this(but I want it to start at the top left) :
[image]
But when I add more objects it gets fixed and the documentView extends from its bottom like this:
[image]

I add a view as the NSScrollViews documentView like this:

```
scrollingView.documentView = contentViewIB2
```

Then I add the required constraints for top pin , left pin , height and width of the documentView like this :

```
    topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentViewIB2
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentViewIB2.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0)

    leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentViewIB2
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentViewIB2.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0)
```

I adjust the width and height of contentViewIB2 as I add objects to it.

Comment: Heres my project in case... : (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64067896/infinite_ubject_test%20copy.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems for the documentView to start at the top left , its coordinate system must be flipped .
You can flip it by subclassing NSView like this :

```
class FlippedView: NSView {
    override var flipped:Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

And then assigning it to contentViewIB2 :

```
Var contentViewIB2 : FlippedView
```

**Swift 4.2**

The override var has been renamed to 'isFlipped'. Everything else worked great.

```
class FlippedView: NSView {
    override var isFlipped:Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```